# Write on stdout by several sub processes on the same Shell of the parent process

Tags: unix, process, fork, stdout, read-write

I have a process which does multiple forks, generating several sub processes which have to write on stdout. So, the messages of the different sub processes might cross with themselves. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have three processes, each trying to output an infinite series of lines composed of four characters followed by a newline:

```
void four(char c);

int main()
{
    //insert your own error checking
    pid_t p0, p1, p2;
#define PROC(pid,str) pid=fork(); if(0==pid) four(str);
    PROC(p0,'a');
    PROC(p1,'b');
    PROC(p2,'c');

    waitpid(p2, 0,0);
    waitpid(p1, 0,0);
    waitpid(p0, 0,0);

}
```

If your `four` function is:

```
void four(char c)
{
    for(;;){
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
            putchar(c);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

and you pipe your program into this grep invocation:

```
./a.out |grep -v -e aaaa -e bbbb -e cccc
```

You'll get matches that demonstrate your problem.

The easiest way to solve this is by relying on the Linux guarantee that it won't break `write` calls aimed at a pipe if the `write` arguments are smaller than the pipe buffer size (defaults to `4KiB` on my system (you can get the size from the `ulimit` shell builtin).

```
void four(char c)
{
    for(;;){
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
            putchar(c);
        putchar('\n');
        fflush(stdout); 
        //the stdout buffer is surely larger than 5
        //so this is 1 `write`
    }
}
```

If you want to be more portable and robust, you can use a lock on a shared file:

```
  void four(char c)
  {
    int fd;
    fd = open("/proc/self/exe", O_RDONLY); 

    for(;;){
        if(0>flock(fd, LOCK_EX))
           perror("flock");

        for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
            { putchar(c); fflush(stdout); }
        putchar('\n'); fflush(stdout);
        //the pipe buf guarantee won't save us here
        //given all these flushes

        //but this lock will
        if(0>flock(fd, LOCK_UN))
           perror("flock");
   }
}
```

Alternatively, can also set file locks with `fcntl`.

Answer (score 0):

By "cross themselves", I presume you mean that you are worried about output being interleaved.  That is, one process attempts to output "Hello, World!", while another prints "Goodbye, Chicago!", and the final output is "Hello, Goodby, World! Chicago!", or similar.  The absolute simplest approach to solving this is to ensure that each message you write is written with a single `write` system call, and that the data is small.  If your messages are less than 1k (or so, the exactly value is system dependent, often 4096, rarely less than 512).  If you invoke `write` with a sufficiently small buffer, the write will be atomic and will not be interleaved with output from any other process.  If your messages won't fit in the size for the system you are on, you will need to use some locking mechanism.